# Is it possible to define points in a T-SNE with column labels?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, seaborn, tsne

I have pandas DataFrame with data in 67382 rows. Where target - datetime in timestamp.

[image]

I create code for plotting, calculate T-sne and I'm visulized T-sne points in code below:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
features = ['TDS7,C', 'TDS8,C', 'TDS9,C', 'target']
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, n_iter=1000, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
points = tsne.fit_transform(df[features])
plt.scatter(points[:0], points[:1], c=df['target'], cmap=sns.color_palette("crest", as_cmap=True))
plt.title(title, fontsize=20, y=1.03)
plt.xlabel(xlabel, fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(ylabel, fontsize=16)
```

[image]

But, it is possible to mapping labels of column to points (determine which point to which column) and legend as below picture?
For, example:

[image]

Where, Population A - TDS7, Population B - TDS8, Population C - TDS9.

Comment: If you do a tsne on the columns `['TDS7,C', 'TDS8,C', 'TDS9,C']`, you are treating each column as a variable, and every row as an observation

Comment: So your annotation on the tsne has to be row-wise or observation, but I suspect this is not the intention of your analysis.